# Quebra de linha em arquivo CSV causa erro durante a importação

Tags: c#, .net

A aplicação precisa ler um arquivo .csv que é gerado automaticamente por uma aplicação externa (Não temos controle sobre essa).

O arquivo .csv tem 60 "colunas" (após leitura e separação dos valores).

O problema é que em alguns casos, ocorre uma quebra de linha no arquivo. Exemplo de linha com quebra:

> teste;teste;teste;"quebra de
>
> linha"; teste;teste

Quando o correto seria:

> teste;teste;teste;"quebra de linha"; teste;teste

No exemplo a aplicação esperaria 6 valores, porém, por conta dessa quebra de linha a aplicação só recebe 4 valores e acaba acusando que:

> O índice estava fora dos limites da matriz.

Segue código de leitura do arquivo.

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(caminho do arquivo)) {
    while (!reader.EndOfStream) {
        var linha = reader.ReadLine();
        var valores = linha.Split(';');
        var minhaClasse = new MinhaClasse(){
            Valor1 = valores[0],
            Valor2 = valores[1],
            Valor3 = valores[2],
            Valor4 = valores[3],
            Valor5 = valores[4],
            Valor6 = valores[5]
        }
    }
}
```

Eu não tenho controle de quando ou qual campo vai vir com quebra de linha, como resolver isso para que eu possa ler toda a linha do .csv sem me preocupar com quebra de linha.

Devo mudar a forma como estou lendo o arquivo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se é a forma mais correta porem foi a que me atendeu. (Obs. A resposta é só para poder finalizar a pergunta).

Usando a biblioteca

> using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

Fiz a leitura do arquivo usando o *TextFieldParser*. Ficou desta forma.

```
//Realiza a leitura do arquivo.
using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(Caminho do arquivo)){

    //Informa qual o delimitador dos campos.
    parser.Delimiters = new string[] { ";" };

    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        //Lê todos os campos da linha e os retorna como uma matriz
        var valores = parser.ReadFields();
    }
}
```

Novamente, não sei se é a forma mais adequada porem foi a que resolveu meu problema pois as quebras de linha são ignoradas.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta usar uma expressão regular para remover quebras de linha na variável `linha`. Por exemplo, abaixo de `var linha`, adicione esse código aqui:

```
linha = Regex.Replace(input, @"\r\n?|\n", linha);
```

Dessa forma, antes de você executar o `linha.Split(';')` a linha estará "limpa" (sem quebras de linha).

Comment: Nesse caso não funciona pois não existe uma quebra de linha "\r\n". O que existe no arquivo são 2 linhas para uma única informação (se abrir como txt vera 2 linhas para um valor). Assim quando uso o reader.ReadLine() ele não entende que o valor continua na linha de baixo, ele acaba lendo como 2 linhas de valores distintos.